# add aria-expanded and tabindex values to parent based on current URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, wai-aria

I'm creating a jQuery-powered, WAI-ARIA tree menu for a site that doesn't have any server-side capabilities. Because of this, my only way of changing the menu dynamically is to check the current URL and compare it against the current file. For a match, I need to do all of these things:

1. Add a class of "current" to the `<li>` element that holds the `<a>` element that matches the current page's URL
2. Add a class of "current" to the `<li>` element that holds the `<ul>` element that holds the `<li>` element that holds the `<a>` element that matches the current page's URL
3. Set the `aria-expanded` attribute to `true` on the `<li>` element targeted in number 2 above
4. Set the `tabindex` attribute to `0` on the child `<a>` element of the `<li>` element targeted in number 2 above (NOT the `<a>` that is actually the current page)

Here's what the resulting HTML should look like (if "owls.html" is the current page):

```
<nav id="nav-sub">
 <ul role="tree">
  <li role="treeitem" class="tree-parent current" aria-expanded="true"><a href="" tabindex="0">Birds</a>
    <ul role="group">
      <li role="treeitem"><a href="ducks.html">Ducks</a></li>
      <li role="treeitem"><a href="geese.html">Geese</a></li>
      <li role="treeitem" class="current"><a href="owls.html">Owls</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li role="treeitem" class="tree-parent" aria-expanded="false"><a href="" tabindex="-1">Cats</a>
    <ul role="group">
      <li role="treeitem"><a href="lions.html">Lions</a></li>
      <li role="treeitem"><a href="tigers.html">Tigers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

I've gotten this bit of jQuery to do the trick for items 1 through 3:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var pathname = (window.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]);
  $("#nav-sub li a[href='" + pathname  + "']").parents(".tree-parent").attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
  $("#nav-sub li a[href='" + pathname  + "']").parents("li").addClass("current");
});
```

However, I'm a JavaScript/jQuery newbie, so I'm not sure if this is the best or most efficient way to do what I want. If anyone can suggest a better way to approach it, I'd appreciate it!

But I don't know how to achieve item 4, adding the tabindex value to the first-level `<a>` element, because it's not actually a parent/ancestor of the current page's `<a>` element. What can I add to my script to target this `<a>` element and change its tabindex value from -1 to 0?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use

```
$("#nav-sub li a[href='" + pathname  + "']").closest('.tree-parent').next('a').attr('tabindex','0');
```

Also, I'd probably set a variable to `$("#nav-sub li a[href='" + pathname  + "']")` so I don't have to keep traversing the tree to get it. Possibly the same with the tree-parent if I'm using it more than once.

I haven't really tested that - but something like that should get what you want.

Comment: One further comment - your regex will work unless you have #something added to it for some reason. Your current regex will return owls.html#something and then fail to match the urls in the href attributes. Something to be aware of.

Comment: Here's the final code Andrew came up with off-site:

    $(document).ready( function () {
    var pathname = (window.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]);
    var currA = $("#nav-sub li a[href='" + pathname  + "']");
    var treeParent = currA.closest(".tree-parent");
    treeParent.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
    currA.parents("li").addClass("current");
    treeParent.children('a').first().attr('tabindex','0');
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
var $treeParent = [current <a> element].closest('.tree-parent');
$('> a', $treeParent).attr('tabindex', 0);
```